# Is it possible to style the new node page?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

Is it possible (with Drupal 7) to style the new node page?

I can add content by going to `node/add/article`, but I want this to be on its own URL and styled like my site's theme.

Is this the correct way to go about this? Or is it better to create a new module with validation to submit data back to the database?

Comment: You can Change the url by setting alias and style it like any other page with css

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is too broad. The answer to _Is it possible with Drupal 7 to style the new node page?_ is _yes_, but I don't think that is going to help you much. Did you try doing it? What problems do you have in doing it? Did you check you didn't set Drupal to use the administration theme also when editing a node? The last two questions are subjective.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being too broad, so I want to have my users add content to content types but have the page and the form styled like my custom theme, so it doesn't look like your using Drupal, but I want to have the flexibility of adding new fields in without the need to edit a template file and create new form validation. I want to know if there if I can create a new template such as `page--node--edit.tpl.php` and call a php function that renders the form around my Frontend page style.

Comment: I would want to hide some features such as allowing the user to set the url path and menu options and comment settings, these are features that users shouldn't be able to have, I imagine that this might be controlled from the permission page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style your node edit or add form by adding `page--node--edit.tpl.php`

or check [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565) for more Suggestions.

Comment: @argiepiano maybe because it worked? :O

Comment: Sorry, it does work! I stand corrected. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to appearance/theme settings, here you have your theme on, but most probably also an admin theme, in the bottom of the page, your admin theme is selected. Here you will also find a checkbox, make sure this is not selected. This makes new node page use the admin-theme.

Comment: Yes, this probably answers to _I want this to be on its own url and styled like my sites theme._